# does CSS overflow: auto; works only when height is set explicitly and not in percent?

Tags: css, height, overflow, percentage

My question is simple but I haven't found a direct answer yet. I have a `<ul>` element and I want to set the `overflow: auto;` while the `height` is in percentage and not in absolute units like pixel or em. but it doesn't work. I mean it acts as if I never set any overflow attribute. Whereas, when I set the height by px or em it works just fine. So, does `overflow:auto;` require us to set the height in absolute units to work? in other words, why doesn't it work with height in percentage?

UPDATE:

my code is something like this:

```
<div id="parent" style="height:90%">
   <ul id="child" style="height:90%; overflow:auto;">
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

When you set `width` or `height` to be, for example, `90%` it essentially means that that element will take `90%` of it's parent property. Now, if the parent is also in percent, then it will depend on the parents parent.

So in your code

```
<div id="parent" style="height:90%">  --Take 90% height of parent element which is ... ?
   <ul id="child" style="height:90%; overflow:auto;">  --Take 90% height of the parent which is the "parent" element
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

So in order to have this work you need to have a parent element somewhere in the hierarchy with a fixed height (e.g in `px`).

For example, this will work:

```
<div style="height:200px">
  <div id="parent" style="height:90%">
     <ul id="child" style="height:90%; overflow:auto;">
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this scenario, `parent` will be `180px` (90% of 200px) and `child` will be `162px` (90% of 180px).

Check this [**Live Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/gu5v9pnc/).

Comment: Dear Chris, So to sum up. I HAVE TO set a fixed height somewhere in hierarchy. I was hoping that as there a default height (browser perhaps), the percentage will be calculated proportional to that. :(

Comment: Either set `body` or `html` to have `height: 100%` (or both), and then also on your div. Otherwise you can use `100vh` on your div.